# Resilience4j exception handling

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I'm trying to integrate fault tolerance in a microservice by using Resilience4j library.
I have: 
**build.gradle**:

```
...
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    lombokVersion = '1.18.10'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }
 dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
 }
}
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.sample'
sourceCompatibility = '11'
configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR8")
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'


    compile 'io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:1.7.0'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
}
```

**application.yml** file:

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  configs:
    default:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
      slidingWindowSize: 5
      minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
      automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
      waitDurationInOpenState: 5s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
      recordExceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
        - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        - java.io.IOException
      ignoreExceptions:
        - com.example.githubtest.BusinessException
    shared:
      slidingWindowSize: 100
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 30
      waitDurationInOpenState: 1s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
      ignoreExceptions:
        - com.example.githubtest.BusinessException
  instances:
    serviceA:
      baseConfig: default
```

**Rest Controller**:

```
...
@RestController
public class MyController {
    private final RestTemplate rest;

    public MyController() { this.rest = new RestTemplate(); }

    @GetMapping(path = "foo")
    @CircuitBreaker(name = "serviceA", fallbackMethod = "customFallback")
    public String foo() {
        throw new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "This is a remote exception");
    }
    @GetMapping(path = "bar")
    public String bar() {
        // Does not get to OPEN state
        return invokeService();
    }

    @CircuitBreaker(name = "serviceA", fallbackMethod = "customFallback")
    public String invokeService() {
        throw new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "This is a remote exception");
    }

    public String customFallback(Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof CallNotPermittedException) {
            System.out.println("Call no permitted!");
        }
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return "Fallback default return";
    }
}
```

There are 2 endpoints: foo & bar

"foo" mapper wrapped with circuit breaker annotation which eventually opens the circuit after N failures
"bar" mapper invokes another method with some business logic and invokes a method wrapped with circuit breaker annotation. In this case, I'm not able to reach OPEN state to handle these scenarios properly according to business rules. I always get failures.

What should I do or change in order to start reaching OPEN state in the second case to be able to handle call not permitted exceptions properly?

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way Spring AOP works, the proxies are skipped if you invoke an annotated method from within the same class. You have to extract `invokeService()` into another bean/class.